# Is it not possible to use var parameters in a Delphi anonymous method?

Tags: delphi, parameters, var, delphi-2009, anonymous-methods

Is it not possible to use `var` parameters in anonymous methods? The following example illustrates (SSCCE) the problem I faced:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TTextTransformProc = reference to procedure(var AText: string);

procedure WriteTransformedText(const AText: string; AProc: TTextTransformProc);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := AText;
  AProc(S);
  Writeln(S);
end;

procedure UpperCaseProc(var AText: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(AText) do
    AText[i] := UpCase(AText[i]);
end;

begin
  WriteTransformedText('This is a test.', UpperCaseProc);
  Readln;
end.
```

The code compiles, but when run I get an access violation error (and no upper-case string). If I remove `reference to`, the code works as expected.

Comment: Probably Delphi 2009 bug.

Comment: This code works fine as-is in XE2.

Comment: Works in Delphi 2010 already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a compiler defect. Your code is correct. The compiler is wrong. Until you can get a more modern compiler you'll have to find a work around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my particular case, the best work-around is to use a function returning a string instead.

Comment: That's probably a better design because it is more composable